# How do I get a C# transform in SSIS to allow me to output a null

Tags: c#, ssis, null

I am reading some text from an input file, splitting it into relevant columns, and then trying to convert those columns to the right data type. For Column 2/price adjustment, it is important that when the output of a column is null, this is what is output. The target column can legitimately contain 0 or negative numbers, and the variation is huge, so a dummy such as -1 or even 999999 is no good here.

One of the columns contains either a valid decimal, such as 125.123, the text N.A, or an empty string. I am using Regexp to take care of the text values - or at least they come through as the initialised value as well as the empty strings when testing with a non-null output, so that's fine.

However when I want the output to be null, I always get the error.

Any ideas? I can find all sorts of things showing how to convert it to a default value if it's null, and I can initialise the variable with -100 to achieve that as a default too, but I want the actual output for that column to be null, not any replacement.

I tried GenOutputBuffer.priceadj_IsNull = true but that did not help and might have been a red herring here, as the error is the value is null, not that the output field cannot contain nullable values I guess. I cannot take .Value off or it underlines red. I could try to check if it has a value using .HasValue but then how do I say, if it doesn't have a value, please still put a null in the output?

Relevant sections of the code:

```
string col2str, col3str;
decimal? col2decN, col3decN;

col2decN = null; //DOES NOT WORK WHEN THIS IS NULL
col3decN = -100; //DOES WORK BUT DO NOT WANT A DUMMY FOR COLUMN 2
```

. . .

```
col2str = Regex.Replace(SplitData[2], "[^0-9.]","");

try
{
col2decN = System.Convert.ToDecimal(col2str);
}
catch
{
//NOTHING
}

GenOutputBuffer.AddRow();
GenOutputBuffer.prodid = SplitData[0];
GenOutputBuffer.priceadj = col2decN.Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the _IsNull of that column to true if the parsing of a string to decimal fails

```
decimal dOut;
            if (decimal.TryParse(SplitData[1],out dOut))
            {
                Output0Buffer.C2 = dOut;
            }else
            {
                Output0Buffer.C2_IsNull = true;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works now! I clearly had misunderstood how to use _IsNull.